# Finding event horizon and ergosphere

Tags: general-relativity, black-holes, event-horizon, kerr-metric

I am trying to calculate the event horizon and ergosphere of the [Kerr metric](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kerr_metric). However, I could not seem to find a proper derivation or formula to calculate the event horizon and ergosphere. Could someone point me to the appropriate derivations or formulas?

Comment: These are given in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kerr_metric#Important_surfaces)

Comment: It'd be useful to see your current calculations - it only involves finding when metric components vanish.

Comment: Are the appropriate components vanishing extendable to other black holes i.e. is the way of finding the event horizon and ergosphere always the same?

Comment: [Cross-posted in PF](https://www.physicsforums.com/threads/finding-event-horizon-and-ergosphere.1011756/)

Answer (score 1):

To find the event horizon, one always solves $g^{rr}=0$. Consider a hypersurface of constant $r$ far away from the black hole. $g^{rr}$ is spacelike here. As you move the surface toward the black hole, you may reach a point where the hypersurface $r =$ constant becomes null. If you reduce the radius further, these hypersurfaces become timelike, and hence the null hypersurface does not allow these timelike curves to go to infinity. Thus the null hypersurface is an event horizon.
Since it is a null hypersurface, its normal vector must be null, which gives $g^{\mu\nu}(\partial_{\mu}r)(\partial_{\nu}r)=0$, or $g^{rr}(\partial_{r}r)^{2} = 0$, which gives the desired relation.